# How to hide app using Android activity manager?

Tags: android, android-activity, termux, activity-manager, lineageos

I need to hide some apps using terminal from crDroid launcher: com.android.launcher3
But not via "pm disable", but via "am" or some other way to make the apps run in the background but not show up in the launcher

Activity that runs the application hiding menu com.android.launcher3.lineage.trust.Trust.TrustAppsActivity

I assume that it should be like su -c am start com.android.launcher3 somehow to address to lineage.trust.Trust.TrustAppsActivity and further like hide application com.android.someapp, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.